# Formal convergence of an integral over a descending sequence of domains involving a Lebesgue inegrable function.

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

I do hope the title was meaningful and informative.

Royden and Fitzpatrick 4th ed. (updated printing) section 4.5 exercise 37 reads

"Let $f$ be a integrable function one $E$. Show that for each $\epsilon > 0$, there is a natural number $N$ for which if $n \geqslant N$, then $\bigg|\int_{E_n}f\bigg| \lt \epsilon$ where $E_n = \{x \in E \mid\ \mid x\mid \geqslant n\}.$

Now, intuitively this makes sense, so I'm trying to figure out how you would formally state it. I wondered if this would be best as a proof by contradiction. If there does not exist such an n for a given epsilon, then you would have the $\int_{E}f \to \infty$. Is this the right angle? If so, how would you recommend setting this up, or is there a better way?